# Master data table:Identifying wrong record

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have a master table where I am storing data of doctor.
I have table HCP where doctor coming from different sources and are getting stored.

```
RowID Name   Professional_designation
1     Robert  MD
1     Robert  RN
2     Andy    MD
```

In above table there is conflicting data for Robert as he can't be MD and RN in our system at same time.

Question:
I need a query which will provide me list of ROWID where Professional_designation is not matching but they have same rowids.
I believe self join will be required but not 100 % sure.

Answer (score 1):

try this to get required Row id's

```
SELECT ROWID,Name
FROM
(
SELECT ROwID,Name,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ROWID,Name ORDER BY Professional_designation) as seqNum
FROM HCP
) Tmp
WHERE seqNum > 1
```

You can get list of doctors records with non matching Professional_designation in HCP table using **self join** like below

```
select t1.* from HCP t1
join HCP  t2 on t1.RowID = t2.RowID and t1.Name=t2.Name
where t1.Professional_designation<>t2.Professional_designation
```

Comment: FROM keyword is giving error.FROM keyword not found where expected

Comment: in first query there was a comma missing , i have corrected it , check now

Comment: This should be marked as the answer. + 1. Just to add, you can use the second query (self-join) to get the `RowID`'s as well by just changing the `SELECT t1.*` to `SELECT DISTINCT t1.RowID`. Though obvious, I think it would be worthwhile to explicitly mention it.

Comment: Still giving error.SQL command not properly ended.Error location: ) As Tmp

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you can do it using self join.

```
select distinct h1.Row_id from hcp h1 join hcp h2 on h1.name=h2.name where h1.row_id=h2.row_id and h1.Professional_designation != h2.Professional_designation;
```